# Trying to create dockerfile for selenium-node-firefox

Tags: node.js, docker, selenium, firefox

I'm trying to create a dockerfile for my Node application that uses Selenium WebDriver. I tried the code below, it creates a directory for node, install geckodriver and firefox.

```
FROM node:12

WORKDIR /usr/app

COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install

# Install geckodriver
RUN wget https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases/download/v0.24.0/geckodriver-v0.24.0-linux64.tar.gz 
RUN tar -xvzf geckodriver-v0.24.0-linux64.tar.gz 
RUN chmod +x geckodriver 
RUN mv geckodriver /usr/local/bin/

# Install firefox
RUN wget "https://download.mozilla.org/?product=firefox-latest&os=linux&lang=pt-BR" -O firefox.tar.bz2
RUN tar -jxvf  firefox.tar.bz2 -C /usr/local/bin/

COPY . .

EXPOSE 3000

CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

The error I receive is `SessionNotCreatedError: Expected browser binary location, but unable to find binary in default location, no 'moz:firefoxOptions.binary' capability provided, and no binary flag set on the command line`. So, the geckodriver doesn't find the firefox binary. I guess isn't setting the firefox well in PATH system, I try to call `firefox --version` and not found.

The `index.js` only do:

```
  const { Builder } = require('selenium-webdriver');
  const driver = await new Builder().forBrowser('firefox').build();
  await driver.get('https://google.com');
```

Comment: Your firefox is being unzipped to /opt/, is /opt in your container Path?

Comment: Try unzipping it on /usr/local/bin, might help.
Another thing to try is looking where does Selenium expect to your binary be from docs: https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/javascript/module/selenium-webdriver/firefox.html

There is this line: `For Linux, Firefox will always be located on the PATH: $(where firefox).`

Comment: @FábioCorreia, I've already tried this, I can use the `whereis` in `docker exec` to check it and looks ok, returning the expected path (tried for usr/local/bin and usr/bin), but when I check with `firefox --version` returns not found.
Also I've tried install firefox for `RUN apt-get install libdbus-glib-1-2 -y` and I had the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve the problem with this dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt install nodejs -y
RUN apt install npm -y
RUN node -v

WORKDIR /usr/app

COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install

RUN apt install wget -y
RUN wget https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases/download/v0.29.0/geckodriver-v0.29.0-linux64.tar.gz 
RUN tar -xvzf geckodriver-v0.29.0-linux64.tar.gz 
RUN chmod +x geckodriver 
RUN mv geckodriver /usr/local/bin/

RUN apt install firefox -y
RUN export MOZ_HEADLESS=1

COPY . .

EXPOSE 3000

CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

I've changed the firefox installation way and added `export MOZ_HEADLESS=1`